# Using Python and Selenium to change Date Values and download CSV files

Tags: python, selenium, date

Using Python via Selenium to change the values in a date widget on Investing.com

I would like some assistance with using Python and Selenium to download Historical Data from Investing.com.

After landing on the website:
https://www.investing.com/equities/barclays-africa-group-ltd-historical-data

I would like to have the program click on the date widget, change the starting date to 1 January 2012, update the table and download the CSV file.  The issue I cannot click on the date widget and update the start date by entering the date via the send_keys() function.  Instead the date widget does not update and the program loops indefinitely.

The code I have thus far looks as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.investing.com/equities/barclays-africa-group-ltd-historical-data')

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]')))
browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]').click()

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]')))
browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]').click()

browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]').clear()

browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]').send_keys('01/01/2012')

browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/button').click()

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div[7]/div/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/time'),'01/30/2023'))
browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a').click()
```

Comment: Update the question withthe relevant HTML and your code trials.

Comment: I'm trying to create a program that loops through about 500 stocks and downloads historical data in csv file format from a specific starting date.  The issue with the code is that I cannot change the starting date using selenium as I cannot select the date widget, clear the starting date and replace it with a desired starting date. Performing this task manually will take forever.  The code I have shared has been modified for the ABSA historical stock price data.  I hope this provides more clarity.

Comment: the problem is date field is not writeable. You can only select date. You need to change your flow as to find date by clicks, not but send keys

Comment: @MahsumAkbas thank you for your response.  I am struggling to find the element that is clickable, any advice?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that the date picker menu is a popup rather than a webelement, hence it is not present in the HTML and so cannot be controlled with selenium

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for selectors:
**CSS Selectors:**

```
div.DatePickerWrapper_input-text__PDRoD.DatePickerWrapper_center__zPpJy
```

**Xpath:**

```
//div[@class='DatePickerWrapper_input-text__PDRoD DatePickerWrapper_center__zPpJy']
```

You can see secreenshot